# I'd like to have a clear report of non-updated files (because of conflicts) during a perforce update

Tags: perforce

When I do an update and zillions of files are updated, I often miss the one that aren't merged because of conflicts. The only way I have is to go through all my changelists and look at file icons.

Isn't there a nicer way ? even a console based command would do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line,

```
p4 resolve -n
```

will list each file with unresolved conflicts.

In p4v, you can right-click on the root of your depot or workspace and select "Resolve" to get a window where you can resolve conflicts interactively.

Answer (score 3):

You could immediately do an update again, which this time would just print out the conflicts.  If you are using p4v, make sure you have the log showing, as the results should scroll through there.